# Check duplicate before inserting in database from CSV upload in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

When uploading the csv file it will check whether email and phone numbers are already inserted or not.

I am facing problems with the if condition which checks for these inputs.

For the mysqli_num_rows() function, I am not getting any values and also will it create any problem for CSV problem.

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST["Import"])){
    $filename=$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
    if($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 0)
    {
        $file = fopen($filename, "r");
        while (($emapData = fgetcsv($file, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE)
        {
            $contractorId=$_SESSION['id'];
            $flag=false;

            $SQLCheckEmail = "SELECT * FROM user where USER_EMAIL='$emapData[1]'";
            $result_check_Email = @mysqli_query($conn,$SQLCheckEmail);
            $row_check_Email=mysqli_num_rows($result_check_Email);
            if($row_check_Email>0){
                $flag=true;
                echo "This user email ".$emapData[1]." has already been added.";
            }
            if($flag!=true){
                //It wiil insert a row to our subject table from our csv file`
                $sql = "INSERT into user (`contractor_id`,`USER_EMAIL`, `USER_ADDRESS`, `USER_PHONE`, `USER_NAME`,USER_SEX,USER_AGE,USER_BIRTHDAY) 
                        values('$contractorId','$emapData[1]','$emapData[2]','$emapData[3]','$emapData[4]','$emapData[5]','$emapData[6]','$emapData[7]')";
                 //we are using mysql_query function. it returns a resource on true else False on error
                $result = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
                if(! $result )
                {
                    echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
                    alert(\"????????????CSV?????????????????\");
                    </script>";
                }
            }

         }
         fclose($file);
         if($flag!=true){
             //throws a message if data successfully imported to mysql database from excel file
             echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
                        alert(\"CSV???????????????\");
                        window.location = \"index.php\"
                    </script>";
         }
        //close of connection
        mysql_close($conn); 
     }
}    
?>
```

Comment: That's a very vague problem statement. Any way you could share a few more details about the exact problem? (Such as expected input/output vs. what currently happens)

Comment: input is (user name,email,phone,address etc) from csv. and current situation is- its not preventing duplicate entry.and the problem is in 
    $SQLCheckEmail = "SELECT * FROM user where     USER_EMAIL='$emapData[1]'";
    $result_check_Email = @mysqli_query($conn,$SQLCheckEmail);
    $row_check_Email=mysqli_num_rows($result_check_Email);
and there is again one phone check.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't solve this on application level. Let the database do the job for you. For each record doing a separate `select` statement will result in horrible performance.

You seem to check, if an entry already exists based on a column `email`. Have a `unique` index on that column. Then you can simply do

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'file_name.csv'
IGNORE /*with this it checks based on the unique index on email, if the record already exists*/
INTO TABLE tbl_name /*adjust your table name*/
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' /*adjust the following to your CSV file*/
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
(email_column, another_column) /*name the columns of your table*/
;
```

You can read more about this command [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html).

Comment: i was not aware of this database adjustment. i need to check "prevent duplicate email","prevent duplicate phone", "prevent duplicate email,phone,name combined". is it the solution for this?

Comment: My solution works on a primary key or a unique key. Both identify each row. If you have more than one row for each user and you have to check for multiple to columns to be unique in one table, you obviously store redundant data. Your table is not normalized. Read about it here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization I'd recommend you work on this issue, rethink your database structure before anything else or you'll experience more trouble like this or worse sooner or later.